# Floating multi-level top navigation with no overflow

Tags: html, css, menu

I recreated my website's top navigation @ http://codepen.io/micsad/pen/mmzrZO (see code below)

I want it to be:

- fixed to the top of the browser viewport
- multi-level with dropdowns
- with top level not overflowing on smaller desktop screens

Setting overflow to hidden on #navigationcss stops overflowing but kills the dropdowns too.

When it's removed, the dropdowns are back but so is overflowing.

Any ideas how to achieve a multi-level fixed top nav whose top level doesn't overflow on smaller desktop screens? What are my options realistically?

```css
/* Horizontal top nav menu */


#navigationbar {
width: 100%; /* change the width of the navigation bar */
height: 50px; /* change the height of the navigation bar */

}

#navigationcss { 
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;
text-align: auto;
background: #E64238;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
width: 100%; /* change the width of the navigation bar */
height: 50px; /* change the height of the navigation bar */
}

#navigationcss ul { 
float: none; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: visible; 
}

#navigationcss li a, #navigationcss li a:link, #navigationcss li a:visited {
color: #ffffff; /* change color of the main links */
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 20px;  /* change the first number for the top/bottom spacing, and the second number for left/right spacing */
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;  
}

#navigationcss li a:hover, #navigationcss li a:active {
color: #ffffff ; /* change the color of the links when hovered over */
background: #87B60E; 
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 20px; /* make sure these are the same as the section above! */
}

#navigationcss li li a, #navigationcss li li a:link, #navigationcss li li a:visited {
background: #87B60E;  /* change the background color of the drop down box */
width: 200px;
color: #ffffff; /* change the color of the drop down links */
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 10px; /* similar to above, change for the spacing around the links */
text-align: left;
}

#navigationcss li li a:hover, #navigationcss li li a:active {
background: #E64238 ; /* change the background color of drop down items on hover */
color: #ffffff; /* change the color of drop down links on hover */
padding: 7px 10px;  /* keep these the same as the above section */
}

#navigationcss li {
float: none; 
display: inline-block; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
}

#navigationcss li ul { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: absolute; 
left: -999em; 
height: auto; 
width: 150px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navigationcss li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li li.sfhover ul { 
left: auto; 
} 

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px; /* change space between logo and first navigation item */
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#promonav1 {
  background: grey;
}

#promonav2 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<!--Start Navigation --> 
<div id='navigationbar'>
  <ul id='navigationcss'><a href='#'><img id='logo' src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=LOGO&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0'/></a>
 
 <li><a href='#'>SECTION 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 7</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 8</a></li>  
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 2</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 7</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 8</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 3</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>    
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 4</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>    
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>         </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 5</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href='#' id='promonav1' target='_blank'>SECTION 6</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' id='promonav2' target='_blank'>SECTION 7</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>KONTAKT</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>   
<!--End Navigation -->
<p>The nav bar overflows onto this line as you shrink the browser.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added display flex to #navigationcss. And as a minor adjustment, also a min-width on the li.

This kinds of problems are easy to solve with flexbox :-)

```css
/* Horizontal top nav menu */


#navigationbar {
width: 100%; /* change the width of the navigation bar */
height: 50px; /* change the height of the navigation bar */

}

#navigationcss { 
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0px;
text-align: auto;
background: #E64238;
z-index: 100;
position: fixed;
width: 100%; /* change the width of the navigation bar */
height: 50px; /* change the height of the navigation bar */
  display: flex;  /* added */
}

#navigationcss ul { 
float: none; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
overflow: visible; 
}

#navigationcss li a, #navigationcss li a:link, #navigationcss li a:visited {
color: #ffffff; /* change color of the main links */
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 20px;  /* change the first number for the top/bottom spacing, and the second number for left/right spacing */
font-family: Verdana;
text-decoration: none;  
}

#navigationcss li a:hover, #navigationcss li a:active {
color: #ffffff ; /* change the color of the links when hovered over */
background: #87B60E; 
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 20px; /* make sure these are the same as the section above! */
}

#navigationcss li li a, #navigationcss li li a:link, #navigationcss li li a:visited {
background: #87B60E;  /* change the background color of the drop down box */
width: 200px;
color: #ffffff; /* change the color of the drop down links */
float: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 10px; /* similar to above, change for the spacing around the links */
text-align: left;
}

#navigationcss li li a:hover, #navigationcss li li a:active {
background: #E64238 ; /* change the background color of drop down items on hover */
color: #ffffff; /* change the color of drop down links on hover */
padding: 7px 10px;  /* keep these the same as the above section */
}

#navigationcss li {
float: none; 
display: inline-block; 
list-style: none; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
min-width: 130px; /* added */
}

#navigationcss li ul { 
z-index: 9999; 
position: absolute; 
left: -999em; 
height: auto; 
width: 150px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#navigationcss li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li li li:hover ul, #navigationcss li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li.sfhover ul, #navigationcss li li li.sfhover ul { 
left: auto; 
} 

#logo {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 40px; /* change space between logo and first navigation item */
  padding-left: 50px;
}

#promonav1 {
  background: grey;
}

#promonav2 {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<!--Start Navigation --> 
<div id='navigationbar'>
  <ul id='navigationcss'><a href='#'><img id='logo' src='https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=9&txt=LOGO&w=50&h=50&txttrack=0'/></a>
 
 <li><a href='#'>SECTION 1</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 7</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 8</a></li>  
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 2</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 7</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 8</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 3</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>    
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 5</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Sublink 6</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 4</a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>    
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li>
      <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>         </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>SECTION 5</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 3</a></li>
        <li><a href='#' target='_blank'>Sublink 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
  <li><a href='#' id='promonav1' target='_blank'>SECTION 6</a></li>
  <li><a href='#' id='promonav2' target='_blank'>SECTION 7</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>KONTAKT</a>
    <ul>
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 1</a></li>
     <li><a href='#'>Sublink 2</a></li> 
      <li><a href='#'>Sublink 3</a></li>    
    </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
</div>   
<!--End Navigation -->
<p>The nav bar overflows onto this line as you shrink the browser.</p>
```

Comment: Great solution. Will have to tweak it to reflect different min-widths on the actual website but otherwise this is exactly what I needed. Cheers!